# Assets not showing the correct upload directory

Tags: add-on, assets

I just upgraded to Assets 2.0 on EE 2.5.3. Installation went smoothly.

However my upload locations aren't acting correctly from within Assets.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
system
html
  assets
  docs
  images
  minified
  themes
```

`html/assets` and `html/docs` are both set up as upload directories in EE.

I'm using Master Config to set them. But even looking through the CP I can see they are correct.
The server path is correct and the Upload Directory URL is absolute, not relative.

But the Assets file browser shows the folder structure of both directories as if they were pointed at the `html` folder. (see screenshot)

[image: Assets screenshot]

Thanks

Comment: Hey Jason, have you updated your indexes yet?

Comment: Yeah, it indexed everything in those folders shown in the screenshots.

Comment: Can you try setting the server paths directly, bypassing Master Config, and then try updating indexes again, and see if they show up correctly?

Comment: Still shows the wrong folders.

Comment: Can you try updating to Assets 2.0.1? If it’s still borked, it might be easier if we could go in and see what’s going on for ourselves. Is this on a public server? If so you can email super admin and FTP credentials to support@pixelandtonic.com.

Comment: Even if you set the server paths directly once those other folders have been indexed the files still reside in the assets_files table.

Comment: How can I un-index the files? Just clear out the exp_assets_index_data table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay here is what I did to get this working correctly. This by no means solves the initial problem but it does get you up and running again.

I basically did what Brandon suggested in his comment—about setting the server paths directly and bypassing the config file. I did this before I ran the module updater or any indexing, so that none of those extra, unwanted, files were added into the exp_assets_files table.

**Steps**

1. Backup your current database just in case this doesn't work for you and you want to get back to here.
2. Restore the database that you backed up in the very first place before all this happened. (You did backup right?). Make sure you delete all tables from the current db and don't just replace them, you want to start clean.
3. If you are using `config['upload_preferences']` array in your config file comment that out.
4. Disable the RogEE Show Me My Assets! if you have it installed.(Don't think this has anything to do with the issues but just to be safe.)
5. Go to file upload preferences and set those manually and update them. Check to make sure they are actually updated, if not you will probably still have something referencing them in a config file.
6. Run the module updater
7. Go to the assets module and update your indexes.
8. Un-comment the `config['upload_preferences']` you comment out in step 3.

That process worked for me. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Glad to hear you got Assets up and running. To clarify: Do you have Master Config installed as well, or were you just entering the $config overrides manually in config.php? And, are the $config overrides working for you for normal Assets use (just not for the update itself), or are they completely useless all around for you?

Comment: Yup using the Master Config.
$config overrides were working fine for me before trying the update. They also seem to be working fine once everything was indexed properly again.

I'm about to update the live server so I will see how that goes and report back.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! We’ll make sure this is fixed for the next update.

Comment: Following that process did work. To confirm, my upload path was not set correctly before setting it using the config override. Brandon, perhaps Assets uses the DB value, and not what it should actually be?

Comment: @Brandon What Jason says could have something to do with it. exp_upload_prefs is only updated when the update button is submitted in whatever environment you are in. So going from local to another environment is likely to screw things up if Assets is indeed indexing from the stored value in exp_upload_prefs

Comment: I was able to use these instructions to successfully install Assets. Rather than comment out config['upload_preferences'], I was able to view the file upload preferences within the control panel and simply click Update for every upload path.  This effectively updated the database, and by not commenting out, I didn't have to manually input the server paths!

Comment: Also, If you keep getting errors of existing tables/columns, check if you have more then 2 tables for assets (exp_assets) in DB, must be only exp_assets and exp_assets_entries before updating.

Answer (score 1):

This should no longer be a problem in the latest version of Assets.  ([Release Notes)](http://pixelandtonic.com/assets/releasenotes).  Thank you!