# Assets 2 update causes PHP errors

Tags: assets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assets not showing the correct upload directory](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/4893/assets-not-showing-the-correct-upload-directory)

I'm running EE 2.5.1 and updating from Assets 1.2.2 to 2.0.1.

I've followed instructions from the Pixel & Tonic docs.

Immediately after running the Assets 2 update, I receive a page filled with the following errors.  It seems like there is an error for every existing assets image.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: 10:Series

Filename: assets/upd.assets.php

Line Number: 712
```

I'm currently setting my upload paths in the EE config.php file:

```
$config['upload_preferences'] = array(
    1 => array(
        'name'        => 'Main Upload Directory',
        'server_path' => $base_path . '/images/uploads/',
        'url'         => $base_url . '/images/uploads/'
    )
);
```

$base_path is a dynamic variable that returns the absolute server path.

I checked the exp_upload_prefs table and the server_path entries do not reflect the upload paths in the config.php file.  Is it possible the Assets 2 updater doesn't recognize these paths either, thus causing the error?

Comment: Think it is kind of related to this thread http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/4893/assets-not-showing-the-correct-upload-directory/4926#comment5008_4926

Comment: I'm receiving also many errors when trying to update. I have my paths in the config like you, and paths are absolute. I hope P&T will fix this with some patch because many people are stuck on this update :(

Comment: @since1976 I believe this is indeed similar to that thread.  I was able to manually update paths in the database, then successfully run the update without errors.

Comment: Jon - did you follow those instructions exactly? If not, can you post your steps here? If that answer solved your problem, I will mark this question as a duplicate so we keep the answer in one place.

Comment: I followed those steps almost exactly, with a minor adjustment to save time. I commented on the other post, so you can mark this as a duplicate. Thanks!