# Assets Upgrade "duplicate" error

Tags: add-on, assets, upgrade, mysql

I was in the process of trying to upgrade my Assets in the EE 2.5.2 install from version 1.1.5 to 2.1.4. I was able to do the update without issue in our development and staging environments, but when I attempted the EXACT same update in production I received this error:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1062

Duplicate entry '1-review_badge.png' for key 'unq_folder_id__file_name'

ALTER TABLE exp_assets_files ADD UNIQUE unq_folder_id__file_name (folder_id, file_name)

Filename: third_party/assets/upd.assets.php

Line Number: 479
```

When I tried to re-submit I was met with this error:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1146

Table 'tmo_ee2.exp_assets' doesn't exist

ALTER TABLE exp_assets MODIFY COLUMN file_path VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL

Filename: third_party/assets/upd.assets.php

Line Number: 403
```

I know the second error is a symptom of the updgrade script already deleting the old `exp_assets` table. Anyone have any idea what's causing the first one? It seems similar to this error: [Assets 2 update causes PHP errors](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/4928/assets-2-update-causes-php-errors) which is related to this one: [Assets not showing the correct upload directory](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/4893/assets-not-showing-the-correct-upload-directory/4926#comment5008_4926)

I AM using the EE Bootstrap Master config, but I am NOT using the `$config['upload_preferences']` options, plus the second support thread above claims this issue is resolved in the latest versions of Assets

Comment: Adam, any chance you recall what you did to resolve this in 2013?