# Assets2: exp_assets_folders table gives error on migration

Tags: database, assets, migration

just upgraded to Assets 2 and must say the visuals are stunning.

When migrating from my local machine to my online development enviroment i got the following SQL error when uploading the database.

```
SQL-query: INSERT INTO  `exp_assets_folders` (  `folder_id` ,  `source_type` ,  >`folder_name` ,  `full_path` ,  `parent_id` ,  `source_id` ,  `filedir_id` ) VALUES ( "2",  "ee",  "Bestanden",  "",  "",  "",  "2" );
MySQL retourneerde: 
#1062 - Duplicate entry 'ee-0-' for key 'unq_source_type__source_id__full_path'
```

this error is caused by the following rules in the import file

```
INSERT INTO `exp_assets_folders` (`folder_id`, `source_type`, `folder_name`, `full_path`, `parent_id`, `source_id`, `filedir_id`) VALUES ("1", "ee", "Afbeeldingen", "", "", "", "1") ; 
INSERT INTO `exp_assets_folders` (`folder_id`, `source_type`, `folder_name`, `full_path`, `parent_id`, `source_id`, `filedir_id`) VALUES ("2", "ee", "Bestanden", "", "", "", "2") ;
```

I think the problems caused by the fact that i'm using the config-bootstrap method to control all path and url information for my installations.

Do you have a way to solve this issue? And is it still possible to control the path information via de config-bootstrap?

Comment: Newly adds upload destinations aren't showing up in ASSETS.

Comment: Did you try this without that master config? If so, check out http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/4893/assets-not-showing-the-correct-upload-directory/4926#comment5006_4926 - but it doesn't sound like it's quite that issue.  How are you exporting your database?  Knowing your process might help with this. Thanks!

Comment: I've had the same problem with EE 2.5.2 and Assets 2.0 + config-bootstrap. Checked out Git repo, dumped and imported database via Sequel Pro and remote connection, successfully re-synced EE Upload Locations (with local overrides), and then the weird part: trying to re-index via Assets just flashes the empty progress bar for a split second and doesn't show any success or error message. All folders just appear to be empty in Assets.

Comment: Update: I upgraded to Assets 2.0.2 after seeing that P&T accounted for this problem, and now all's well.

Comment: Please direct bug reports directly to developers - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Pixel and Tonic updated Assets to account for $config overrides. Update to 2.0.2 and you should be set!

http://pixelandtonic.com/assets/releasenotes

Answer (score 1):

This error seems to relate to the use of the master-config methode of setting up ExpressionEngine. I've reverted back to Assets 1 for the time being while this error is being solved bij Pixel and Tonic.